# Deep Learning DJI Mavic Pro and Guidance SDK Programming Language

Tags: sdk, deep-learning, dji-sdk

I would like to do some Deep Learning tests on the DJI Mavic Pro Drone, but before purchasing it I want to know which programming languages the Guidance SDK uses to develop this scripts and **Is it possible to edit prewritten functions of this SDK?**

I have been searching but I couldn´t find any information about it, I know it is possible to program with ROS in Guidance SDK.
But let's say I have a python Script can I work with it using the mentioned SDK?

For example the Parrot 2.0 Power Drone Quadricopter Edition it is possible to edit its library and prewritten functions, here in GitHub you can see more information of some deep learning project applied to this drone: https://github.com/antriv/Object_Recognition_Drone. But I don't know if the DJI Mavic Pro or any DJI Drone allows this.

If someone has any idea or some website where I can find information it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Guidance SDK is only for developing with the Guidance product: http://www.dji.com/guidance?site=developer

For Mavic, you can use the mobile SDK: http://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/

This will let you write any apps on either iOS or Android using respectively Objective-C/Swift or Java.